# cURL to xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, oauth-2.0, xmlhttprequest

Does anybody know how to translate the following curl command into ajax/ xmlhttpsrequest?

```
curl -d "username=username@company.com&client_secret=123456789&password=pwdgoeshere&grant_type=password&client_id=ReallyLongClientIDGoesHere" -H "Accept: application/json" https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

I would like to achieve something like the following 2 examples , but my code doesn't work:

1)

```
var req = new  XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open( "POST", "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", true); 
  req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  req.send();
```

2)

```
 $.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    headers: myHeaders,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

}).complete(function ( data ) {
    console.log(data.responseText);
});
```

Comment: Well you are not sending the post data

Comment: I don't know how the format the post data for my examples. I am quite new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myUrl",
    data: { 
        "username": username, 
        "VarB": VarB, 
        "VarC": VarC
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function(xhr) {

    }
});
```